# How to trigger fill color of shapes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want when I have a shape (here circles) selectionned and click a button trigger a **color change** of shape selectionned.

For example if I click on red button, the shape background color change to red.

In the below code I try to change background color to red for the shape selectionned but I  have error message: **a property or method not managed by this object**

```
Sub fillColorRed()

 With Selection
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 End With

End Sub
```

How can fix it ?
Also I often get this error, I don't understand how to avoid this type of error.
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works for me. It detects the selected shape. Beware, you must select a shape else you will have an error.

```
  With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(106, 208, 152)
       .Transparency = 0
       .Solid
   End With
```

Comment: You never use shpTemp, why declare?

Comment: @learnAsWeGo Good question. I will update my answer monday. Good weekend!

Comment: I noticed this too but it works fine even with the declaration of this variable. Thank you anyway!